# Proper Translation of "Faith of Nine" to Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am trying to verify the correct translation of the phrase "Faith of Nine" to latin. I typed it in on Google Translate and it gave me the following translation: Fidei Autem Novem.

This is for a potential song title for a lyric that I'm working on.

From the research I've done, Fidei seems to be the correct word for "Faith" and "Novem" seems to be the correct word for "Nine", meaning, the number 9. "Autem" seems to mean "However", or something of the like. I need help with verifying the grammar.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Is "nine" in this context nine individual somethings, or the number nine itself, are is it the nine that have faith or is the nine that you have faith in?

Comment: Hello.Thank you. The title "Faith of Nine" is referring to a fictional faith that is based on the worship on 9 elements. I'm not entirely sure which alternative from your response to choose from.

Comment: @User5504242: Number "novem" does not decline so "fides novem" will not immediately convey your desire. How about "fides rudimentum" = faith of the first-principles"/ "faith of the rudiments"? You could include "novem", but it's less punchy.

Comment: Hm...so Fidei Autem Novem is not the correct translation? The correct translation is Fides Novem?
Faith of the first-principles does not really convey the meaning of the song, or lay any emphasis on the elements/the number 9, which is highly important in this context.

Comment: @user5504242: "Fidei Autem Novem" = "Nine is however of the Faith"; or "to"/ "for" the faith". Fides Novem" could be translated as "Faith of the Nine"; but numbers, above three, do not decline; without the genitive "of nine", it looks like "Faith Nine". Alternatively, "fides novem elementorum" = "faith of the nine elements".

Comment: All right. Then I understand. Thank you for your answer. Fides Novem, or Fides Novem Elementorum would be more correct in other words. It just doesn't sound as punchy and powerful as my original idea. I will have to figure out a different title based on your answer.